# Reading Android.mk files in sub-dirs recursively

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I would just like to ask what should be written in the Android.mk file to also call the mk files in the sub-directories of the current directory. 

Example:
/packages/Android.mk
/package/groupA/Android.mk
/packages/groupA/AppA/Android.mk
/packages/groupA/AppB/Android.mk

I know that by using `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)`, the Android.mk file in the immediate sub-directory will be read (example: /package/groupA/Android.mk). However, /packages/groupA/AppA/Android.mk and /packages/groupA/AppB/Android.mk will not be read.

I wonder if there is other macro that do the recursive reading of the Android.mk for all sub-directories.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most convenient solution is putting `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` command also inside `/package/groupA/Android.mk` file.

However, if you want only third-level mk files then you can use the following command:

```
include $(wildcard $(call my-dir)/*/*/Android.mk)
```

And here is a fully recursive solution, but it relies on `find` command from the shell:

```
include $(filter-out $(call my-dir)/Android.mk,$(shell find $(call my-dir)/ -type f -name Android.mk))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. actually, I got it working without having to write `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` in the mk file. Looks like there was a problem in the script that reads all the mk file. I will try your answer sometime. I know it will be helpful to others.